# position:fixed; in css not working for IE6\IE7

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Position:fixed to work on IE 6/7/8 and mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711922/positionfixed-to-work-on-ie-6-7-8-and-mozilla)

position:fixed; in css not working for IE6\IE7. What is the workaround for this? Please advise me

Comment: what doctype are you using? I think it works in XHTML strict?

Comment: Here is explained in detail: http://tagsoup.com/cookbook/css/fixed/

Answer (score 1):

> IE 5/6 don’t support position: fixed IE7 has a strange bug; see page.

Taken from 
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this solution:

http://ryanfait.com/position-fixed-ie6/